# How to fix <grid> containers to be the same height as the highest container in the same row?

Tags: html, css, material-ui

I'm struggling to work this out with CSS, I'm trying to make my accordion containers inside my layout to each become the same height as the highest item on the same row, in theory this would make a nice clean and responsive layout where my items are the same height and width:

However currently things like off as the heights of my accordion's are not the same,

Here is a quick draw of my problem:

[image]

The accordions each have an icon, title text, and subtitle text.

**Current Problems are:**

- Each accordion has different amounts of characters for title and subtitle, which leaves some containers to be smaller or larger than the rest. The icons also don't help as they push the text even more.

I managed to make an representation of my problem in the sandbox below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-leaf-nz9x0?file=/src/index.js

Ideally, the icon, text, and subtitle text would each be aligned horizontally on the same line for each accordion item.

How can I fix this with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

To make all elements to be the same height, the code below should do it depending on if you want all of the elements to have the same height or just all elements in a row to have the same height.

```
.parent{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; // two equal columns

    // choose one or other of these 
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr; // all elements the same as the tallest element
    grid-template-rows: 1fr; // elements in a row have the same height. Height is different for each row

    gap: 1rem; // gap between each element
}
```

Comment: Hi Sean, thank you for the help. I’m a little confused on where I add this snippet in my layout. Are you referring to the parent <grid> that’s wrapped around all of them?

Comment: Yup that's it. The parent container that is wrapping all these grid elements

Comment: I haven't been able to code the code working, implementing the gap property also seems to be pushing my whole grid to the left and only allowing one accordion per row.

Comment: the `grid-template-rows` in this case is not needed since you defined the `grid-auto-rows`

Comment: I said that you should choose one of those properties depending on which use case you need